# How can I set default password expiration policy for postgresSQL server?

Tags: postgresql, passwords, psql, policy

I'm running a Aurora postgres DB server, and I want to set the password expiration policy so that an user can change his password and it will be expired after 1 month.

I know that I can create an user with password expiration date such as below.

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format($$CREATE USER myuser WITH PASSWORD 'password12345678' VALID UNTIL %L$$, NOW() + interval '1 month');
END
$do$;
```

However, I don't want to force my users to input `VALID UNTIL` by themselves, because I don't want to give such controls to my user. I want to guarantee that my users can change password but they should change within a fixed duration.

As an admin, I will create a db user only once. After that, each user uses the db user but they change their passwords whenever a certain period of time passes.

In short, I'm looking for something in postgres that can play the same role as mysql's `default_password_lifetime`.

Is it possible? How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set a password life time in PostgreSQL. Also, you cannot enforce password complexity rules. If you need any of that, use an [authentication method](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html) that does not use passwords in the database, but some central identity management solution that can enforce your requirements.